# Check interval in icinga2?

Tags: icinga2, icinga, icingaweb2, icingaweb

I am trying to change the check_interval time for a single domain to 5 minutes but icinga2 doesn't override it. The checks are done every 1 minute. Here is my conf.
The main domain examplemanager.com Icinga checks for 5 minutes but I want test.examplemanager.com to be checked every 7 minutes and examplemanager.com/test/admin to check every 5 minutes. how can I do that?

[configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUl0p.png)

[lastchek details in icinga2 dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGZAm.png)

Answer (score 0):

check_interval doesn't inherit from vars.

THis way it's vars.check_interval and not check_interval.

I always have an generic service include that does

```
if (service.vars.check_interval) {
  check_interval = service.vars.check_interval
}
```